# Cannot resolve constructor JSONobject (Integer)

Tags: android, android-json

I'm trying to make a program that will display multiple titles with  pictures under them.  I looked over stackoverflow, and can't get any of the suggestions to work for me. All my errors are within private void ShowJSON

```
package br.exemplozxingintegration;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



public class ForthActivty extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {

    private EditText  pastetext;
    private ClipboardManager myClipboard;
    private ClipData myClip;
    private Button btn;
    private Button btn2;
    private EditText textView1;
    private Button buttonGet;
    private TextView textViewResult;
    private ImageView ImageView1;

    private ProgressDialog loading;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forth_activty);
        myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        pastetext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPaste);
        btn.performClick();


        textView1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        buttonGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
        textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
        ImageView1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        buttonGet.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
        btn2.performClick();


    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void paste(View view) {
        ClipData cp = myClipboard.getPrimaryClip();
        ClipData.Item item = cp.getItemAt(0);
        String text = item.getText().toString();
        pastetext.setText(text);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}


    private void getData() {
        String qrcode = textView1.getText().toString().trim();
        if (qrcode.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

        String url = ConfigRec.DATA_URL+textView1.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                loading.dismiss();
                showJSON(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(ForthActivty.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

     private void showJSON(Integer response){
    String title="";
    String image = "";
    try {
        JSONArray jarray=new JSONArray(response);
        for( response = 0;response<jarray.length();response++){
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(ConfigRec.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject androidData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        title = androidData.getString(ConfigRec.KEY_TITLE);
        image = androidData.getString(ConfigRec.KEY_IMAGE);
    }} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        textViewResult.setText(title);//+"\nImagine :\t"+ image);
        //int id = >getResources().getIdentifier("http://192.168.1.254/2015/380panel/uploads/images>/sm/"+ image, null, null);
        //ImageView1.setImageURI(id);
        >Picasso.with(this).load("http://192.168.1.254/2015/380panel/uploads/images/sm/+ image).into(ImageView1);

    }
```

And my errors is:

```
Cannot resolve constructor JSONobject(java.lang.Integer)
```

and it's on the line `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);`

Comment: your for loop under showJSON is missing braces, hence cannot resolve jsonObject

Comment: Are your trying to convert your response to JSONArray? And what is this supposed to mean JSONArray.length()?

Comment: Too many errors in your code.

Comment: Cheers, I also modified the result from string to int. But i still get Non-static method length cannot be referenced from a static context, and Cannot resolve constructor JSONobject(java.lang.Integer)

Comment: Try to do like this JSONArray jarray=new JSONArray(response); and use jarray.length() in for loop instead of JSONArray.length()

Comment: Thanks @ajantha, I've done that, and the only error I get is "Cannot resolve constructor JSONobject(java.lang.Integer)". It's on this line " JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);". And I also eddited my code based on what you said

Comment: Post your Json response. It will help to identify your problem

Comment: Please don't misuse the tag `android-studio`. If you question is not specific to the IDE, don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Change showJson(Integer response) to

```
showJson(String response){
String title="";
String image = "";
try {
    JSONArray jarray=new JSONArray(response);
    for( int i= 0;i<jarray.length();i++){
    JSONObject jsonObject = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(ConfigRec.JSON_ARRAY);
    JSONObject androidData = result.getJSONObject(0);
    title = androidData.getString(ConfigRec.KEY_TITLE);
    image = androidData.getString(ConfigRec.KEY_IMAGE);
}} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    textViewResult.setText(title);//+"\nImagine :\t"+ image);
    //int id = >getResources().getIdentifier("http://192.168.1.254/2015/380panel/uploads/images>/sm/"+ image, null, null);
    //ImageView1.setImageURI(id);
    >Picasso.with(this).load("http://192.168.1.254/2015/380panel/uploads/images/sm/+ image).into(ImageView1);

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it runs without any errors, but it doesn't display when i get to the activity.

Comment: Any ideea why it doesn't display anything?

Comment: Show the Json you want to parse.

Comment: public class ConfigRec {
    public static final String DATA_URL = "http://192.168.1.254/2015/380panel/includes/php/ajax/actions.php?action=mysql__get_retete&table_name=retete&qrcode=";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
}